# Microsoft excel taking average of a record

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a record in excel, It shows like this '101 to 250' I want to take average of both these numbers. Can any one give a quick formula for this please?
I have almost 2 lac records like this. I want to remove to via formula and add these numbers with formula too

Comment: Thanks for ur answer, I have almost 2 lac records like this. I want to remove to via formula and add these numbers with formula too

Comment: like 100000 records like that. Want to remove 'to' and then get substrings and calculate their average.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
=(LEFT(A1,3)+RIGHT(A1,3))/2
```

Comment: Can u suggest some more dynamic formula, As the numbers can be like 10000-5000 too. What abt that case?

Answer (score 0):

1. If the ranges are solely of the form `<numA><space>to<space><numB>` you can use

   ```
   =AVERAGE(LEFT(D2,FIND(" ",D2)),RIGHT(D2,LEN(D2)-FIND(" ",D2,FIND(" ",D2)+1)))
   ```

   The above formula extracts `<numA>` and `<numB>` using the `<space>`s as delimiters via `FIND`:

   [image]
2. If the ranges are solely of the form `<numA>-<numB>` you can use

   ```
   =AVERAGE(LEFT(D2,FIND("-",D2)-1),RIGHT(D2,LEN(D2)-FIND("-",D2)))
   ```

The above formula extracts `<numA>` and `<numB>` using the `-` as a delimiter via `FIND`:

[image]

3. If the ranges are a mix of (1) and (2) (either `<numA><space>to<space><numB>` or `<numA>-<numB>`) then you can condition on the above averages. The condition is based either string's uniqueness. Below I've used the presence of `-` to discern between the two:

   ```
   =IF(ISERROR(FIND("-",D2)),
     AVERAGE(LEFT(D2,FIND(" ",D2)),RIGHT(D2,LEN(D2)-FIND(" ",D2,FIND(" ",D2)+1))),
     AVERAGE(LEFT(D2,FIND("-",D2)-1),RIGHT(D2,LEN(D2)-FIND("-",D2))))
   ```

   [image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a dynamic formula that will work no matter the length of each number and no matter how many spaces between "to" and each number

```
=AVERAGE(TRIM(MID(A1,1,FIND("to",A1)-1)),TRIM(MID(A1,FIND("to",A1)+LEN("to"),LEN(A1)-FIND("to",A1))))
```